# ffmpeg -ss and -to options seem to affect av synchronity

Tags: ffmpeg

up until now I used the following script for cutting significant parts of video out of a larger video while also selecting the most a/v synchrone audio track amongst several ones present in the input file.

```
infile="2023-04-15 23-46-57.mp4"
outfile="John Rambo.mp4"
starttimestamp=00:00:04
endtimestamp=01:28:51
ffmpeg -i "$infile" -c:a copy -c:v copy -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -ss $starttimestamp -to $endtimestamp "$outfile"
```

(the 0:1 would be changed on a case to case basis, as would the timestamps and filenames)

this has until now worked flawlessly. Yet currently with both ffmpeg 4.4.3 (on my desktop == most recent version on Fedora 35) and 6.0.1 (on my NAS == synology community package) I can not get the A/V to stay in sync like this.
When I am only extracting the audio channel (in this instance 0:1) which is a/v synchrone without cutting a middle segment out the output is in sync. After cutting the file is a/v asynchronous for me.
I already tried cutting in to steps instead of one (intermediate file) and duplicating the -ss and -to parameter to the audio part of the ffmpeg call like following

```
ffmpeg -i "$infile" -c:a copy -ss $starttimestamp -to $endtimestamp -c:v copy -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -ss $starttimestamp -to $endtimestamp "$outfile"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ffmpeg 4.2.4 in an ubuntu WSL instance works fine. which solves the immediate issue of "I-want-this-to-work-now" yet leaves me curious as per why does it work in WSL yet in neither of the two natively ran instances.

Comment: Place both `-ss` and `-to` before `-i`.